# Eclipse errors in projects

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am using eclipse for a project development. Yesterday all my projects were working quite well and today when I opened my eclipse its showing errors on some projects, when I expand the project there is no error markers either in the src folder nor any error in the build path but the error marker is just on the project inside the project there is no error.

How can I remove these error markers from all my projects. I have already tried cleaning all my projects are re-building

Thanks

Comment: are u using maven in your project?

Comment: In some projects yes

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens for no apparent reasons...it happened with me also... 
Search for the problem..
The errors are shown in the Problems view. If it is not opened, go to:

Window > Show View > Problems

Alt+Shift+Q,X(keyboard shortcut)

On your maven project

Right click on that project --

Go to maven

click update project...

It should remove the error

it worked for me...

Give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors in the maven projects I tried it didn't work for me

Comment: ohkz..i thought there are errors in your maven project...check the edit @wearybands

Answer (score 0):

i too have faced this problem many times. I follow below steps to remove errors and it works for me:

1. remove the project from eclipse.
2. go to project and run commands:

`mvn eclipse:clean
mvn clean install
mvn eclipse:eclipse`

3. import back project.